# Toggle button not toggling on Android

Tags: android, android-togglebutton

I have a class with toggle buttons defined like so:

```
public class DeviceControlActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
private ToggleButton b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10, b11, b12;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gatt_services_characteristics);
b2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this); // calling onClick() method
        b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        b3 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // default method for handling onClick Events..
        switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.button2:
                // call writeCharacteristic but concatenate pin #
                if (b2.isChecked()) {
                    b2.setChecked(false);
                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    // do code to send pin# with writeCharacteristic
                    String str = "Pin11,0" + "\n";
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending OFF result=" + str);
                    /*final byte[] tx = str.getBytes();
                    if(mConnected) {
                        characteristicTX2.setValue(tx);
                        mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristicTX2);
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicRX2,true);
                    }*/
                } else if (!b2.isChecked()) {
                    b2.setChecked(true);
                    b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    // do code to send pin# with writeCharacteristic
                    String str = "Pin11,1" + "\n";
                    Log.d(TAG, "Sending ON result=" + str);
                    /*final byte[] tx = str.getBytes();
                    if(mConnected) {
                        characteristicTX2.setValue(tx);
                        mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristicTX2);
                        mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicRX2, true);
                    }*/
                }
                break;
}
}
```

when I run the app and toggle b2, I always get the Sending OFF result part of the if, even though in the xml the toggle buttons are declared as false and the button doesnt toggle on or off.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToggleButton`s, like all `CompoundButton`s, take care of their own checked state upon clicking. Your `OnClickListener` is counteracting that behavior. Instead, use a `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`, and check the `boolean` passed into `onCheckedChanged()` for the new state.

Comment: Great!  extended the right class, implemented method, replaced buttonView and commented out the manual toggle I had. The only issue now is that they should start out as false according to the xml, but on first tap, I get the Sending OFF result, which happens when the b2.isChecked() condition is true.

Comment: That sounds correct to me. If the `Button` starts as _off_, the first click will toggle it to _on_ (`isChecked() = true`), so your `if` block will execute. The `onCheckedChanged()` method fires after the state has changed, so you might need to flip your logic from what you had with the `OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend that you use the check changed listener on your toggle buttons.

```
ToggleButton b2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
b2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new     CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean     isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            // The toggle is enabled
            b2.setChecked(false);
                b2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                // do code to send pin# with writeCharacteristic
                String str = "Pin11,0" + "\n";
                Log.d(TAG, "Sending OFF result=" + str);
                /*final byte[] tx = str.getBytes();
                if(mConnected) {
                    characteristicTX2.setValue(tx);
                    mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(characteristicTX2);
                    mBluetoothLeService.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristicRX2,true);
                }*/
        } else {
            // The toggle is disabled
        }
    }
});
```

With not having seen your XML, it sounds like the onClick method also isn't being called when you click on the button.